# How do I save the median of a column as an integer?

Tags: r, function, median

I am trying to write a function that includes calculating the median of a specific column. The data I am using is name data from the SSA. The summary is below:

```
     name               sex                count             year           rank     
 Length:12736       Length:12736       Min.   :   5.0   Min.   :1880   Min.   :   1  
 Class :character   Class :character   1st Qu.:   7.0   1st Qu.:1881   1st Qu.: 531  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Median :  13.0   Median :1883   Median :1062  
                                       Mean   : 103.4   Mean   :1883   Mean   :1066  
                                       3rd Qu.:  42.0   3rd Qu.:1884   3rd Qu.:1592  
                                       Max.   :9655.0   Max.   :1885   Max.   :2297
```

I am trying to find the median rank of a specific name.

This is my function:

```
    # Return a vector of each year's deviation from the total median
    delta_from_median_vector <- function(names, v_name, v_sex){
      #Find the median count
      names %>%
        filter(name==v_name & sex==v_sex) %>%
            m <- median(rank)
    }
```

This is the error:

```
Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
  'x' must be atomic
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'closure'
```

Comment: Try with `names %>% filter(name==v_name & sex==v_sex) %>% summarise(m = median(rank)) %>% pull(m)`

Comment: That definitely gets the median. But how do I store that as a variable so I can use it later? I tried med <- pull(m) and that doesn't work.

Comment: You could do `med <- delta_from_median_vector(....)` to store the result of your function or if you want to do some steps inside your function do `med <- names %>% ....`